# Gnuplot fails to use a specific number

Tags: gnuplot

I have a very strange problem, which I suspect is due to my pc but I cannot determine what the hell is happening, so I just tried to ask here.

My gnuplot (version 5.0 patchlevel 3) on KDE-neon (which is based upon Ubuntu 16.04) and my i7-3770 core seems to joke on me:

This simple code:

```
plot 10**(-6.5)
```

raises the following error `all points y value undefined!`, while this:

```
plot 10**(-6.49999)
```

(and for what I can understand each other number) works just as expected [of course they raise warnings, but that *is* expected].

I really don't know what to think about this, and even if this is barely a problem for my work, it has made me curse for quite a moment. Has anyone out there some kind of explanation? Or maybe someone else with this problem???

I am really confused. Hope to been clear.

Comment: have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10815033/all-points-y-value-undefined-on-gnuplot

Comment: yep, I have seen it. But I don't think it is applicable in this case, if not because using 6.4999 or 6.50001 works but with 6.5 not. [Only 10**-6.5].

Comment: This would be very strange. Is that in a fresh gnuplot session? What is the result of `print 10**(-6.5)`?

Comment: Now it is the correct number, and everything goes well: what happened in the middle? The HDD broke. I don't know what it could be.
(it was a fresh gnuplot and even a fresh shell)